# Reset a dynamically created radio group inside a table in angular 4

Tags: html, angular, radio-button, radio-group

I have a dynamically created radio group inside a table in my component. I am using a ngFor to create the radio buttons. And there's a clear button outside the ngFor. I want to clear the radio group when the clear button is clicked. 
Below is what I am doing right now, but it only works partially. for example, if I have three radio buttons I can only clear if I select the first one and unable to clear the radio group if I select 2nd or 3rd radio. so can anyone tell me what I am doing incorrectly here or suggest a better way of doing it for my scenario. thank you

html:

```
            <table>
            <tr *ngFor="let member of members; let i = index">
              <td>
               <div class="radio-primary">
                 <input type="radio" #qwerty id="selectId{{i}}">
              </td>
                </tr>
             </table>
            <a (click)="clear()" [innerHTML]="clear"></a>
```

ts file :

```
@ViewChild('qwerty') qwerty: ElementRef;

       clear(): void {
          this.qwerty.nativeElement.checked = false;
   }
```

Comment: Could you create a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/) to give the full code?

Comment: Sure will do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify some following changes in your structure.

```
<table>
            <tr *ngFor="let member of members; let i = index">
              <td>
               <div class="radio-primary">
                 <input type="radio id="selectId{{i}}" name="primaryRadio">
              </td>
                </tr>
             </table>
            <a (click)="clear()" [innerHTML]="clear"></a>
```

Following changes need to be done in .TS file:

```
clear(): void {
 var ele = document.getElementsByName("primaryRadio");
 for(var i=0;i<ele.length;i++) {
   var element = ele[i] as HTMLInputElement;
   element.checked = false;
  }
}
```

Idea is, Radio buttons works with same NAME 
(HTML structure). Set the checked attribute of all radio elements with same name

Comment: I did try that, but i get an error saying that 'Property 'checked' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.'

Comment: It works! Thank you. I am new here, but i hope to learn from you all and contribute too.

Answer (score 0):

There is a reset() method on every HTMLFormElement 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement

```
HTMLFormElement.reset()
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset

You could generate an Array of Controls and iterate over it to reset every single FormControl. Or you define a  FormGroup, add every single Control to this Group and then you reset the Group.

Please have in mind, that setting the value to "false" does **NOT** reset the Control. It'll still be touched for example.

Comment: But my its of type HTMLElement and i do not have a reset method for that. is there anyway i can cast it ? or what else can i do?